# OpenSSL EVP_CIPHER free/release

Tags: openssl, evp-cipher

I can't find any method like `EVP_CIPHER_free` in `openssl/evp.h`. Don't I need to release the EVP_CIPHERs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't. The init function `EVP_CipherInit_ex` is actually initializing variables in EVP_CIPHER_CTX object `ectx`, which you pass as the first argument. Just remember to call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ectx)` when you're done.

Comment: Ah nice. But functions like `EVP_des_cbc()`, `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` and so on doesn't require the context? Aren't these normal ciphers too?

Comment: Those function is used to assign cipher type, not used to do any encryption or decryption. If you want to use EVP to do encryption, you can find examples in OpenSSL source code, such as demos\maurice\example3.c